# Access the id after saving ActiveRecord model

Tags: php, orm, yii2

i have an issue with access to the id of the ActiveRecord model in Yii2 framework. when i save the model i just created, i cannot acquire the id field of new object.

```
$house = new House;
$house->save();

$hid = $house->id;
```

$hid value is empty string ''.

the problem is that i am creating new model, so that i can pass the new id to thread process that is handling file moving while i create db rows. thread starts and after json slicing and array populating, the first insert fail on sql condition (where) statement.

i have researched many answers and they point to several flaws:

1. assignment of pk - i don't assign the new model id field (db handles the pk autoincrement), i receive the $_post body content through json (json has many fields that are not for bulk assignment into main model, so i deal with slicing the json data before $attibutes insert).
2. pk in model rules - i don't have id field in model rules array.
3. fault in the ActiveRecord class - i don't want to hack the base classes of the framework.

later in code i planned to link the models through relations, but i suppose that failed because of this error, so i also use $hid value to populate the foreign key fields in related models.

help. please.

Comment: Does `save()` return `true`?
Try `print_r($house->errors);` after to see if validation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a validation problem  try in this way

```
    $house = new House;
    if ($house->validate()) {       
        $house->save();

        $hid = $house->id;
     } else {

        $errors = $house->errors;
        var_dump($errors)
    }
```

If you see the result of var_dump  the your validation fails (eg: some required fields .. ) and you need change the proper validation rules in your  House Model ..

Otherwise you cant try with

```
  $house->save(false); //this way the validation is not executed
```

*(use save(false) only for debugging porpose)*

Answer (score -1):

thank you scaisEdge and Alex. i have forgot to check the not null columns of the db. yii2 gii module generated the model according to the db schema and i missed the rules fields of the model. i didn't need validation since i was just generating empty row (just pk).

this is the code that passes:

```
$house = new House;
$house->name = 'name'; [field set as required in model rules array]
$house->description = 'description'; [field set as required in model rules array]
$house->save();

$hid = $house->id;
```

convention and configuration, pretty neat.